# Bomb calorimeter enthalpies of straight chained alcohols

Tags: thermodynamics

Can anyone suggest a website which contains the literature values (using a bomb calorimeter) of the enthalpies of n-alcohols?

I have been trying to find it but I am unable to locate bomb calorimeter values (I do not want the bond dissociation energies.

Comment: [Here](http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/organic_thermo.htm) are enthalpy of combustion values for the first 8 n-alcohols.

Comment: You can also get a rough estimate of it by using bond enthalpy calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I searched 'combustion enthalpies of straight chain alcohols' in Google Scholar and found a couple of links to papers that look relevant, see below. Unfortunately one looks like you have to pay for it, but if you're associated with an institution they may give you free access. The other involves cyclic alcohols, obviously not straight chain but maybe helpful nonetheless.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02885455?LI=true

http://actachemscand.dk/pdf/acta_vol_16_p0046-0052.pdf

I would imagine the molar enthalpies of combustion would increase fairly linearly as chain length increases. Each extra carbon in the chain means an extra molecule of CO2 is produced, and the strong C=O bonds formed are the major contribution to the exothermicity of the reaction. Steric or torsional effects in the larger molecules may lead to a slightly smaller than expected increase per carbon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Tom's answer:
According to ["Correlation of Heats of Combustion with Empirical Formulas for Fatty Alcohols" by Freedman et al:](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02885455?LI=true)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 \text{Alcohol Name}& \hline \text{Heat of Combustion (kg-cal/mole)} \\ \hline
\text{Decyl} & 1582    \\ \hline
\text{Lauryl} & 1899\\ \hline
\text{Myristy} & 2202 \\ \hline
\text{Palmityl} & 2512\\ \hline
\text{Stearyl} & 2826 \\ \hline
\text{Arachidyl} & 3138  \\ \hline
\text{Behenyl} & 3453 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

- Samples were 99% pure
- All alcohols are n-alcohols
- Data is based on a minimum of 3 replications
- The bomb calorimeter used was Parr  Adiabatic Oxygen Bomb Calorimeter, Model 1241

The data is out there, but you may have to compile and proccess it depending on how many values you need.